# How to Display a selected grade with its subject?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want to when a user select a dropdown from the list, a group of subjects available for that grade must be displayed with checkboxes next to them

My controller

```
public function create()
    {
       
        $grades = Grade::with('subjects')->orderBy('slug', 'asc')->get();
        
        return view('admin.users.create', compact( 'grades'));
    }
```

Blade file

```
<div class="form-group">
         <select id="grade" name="grade" class="form-control @error('grade') is-invalid @enderror" v-model="selectedSubjects">
                 <option value="">Choose a Grade...</option>
                            @foreach($grades as $grade)
                  <option value="{{ $grade->id }}" {{ old('grade', $grade) == $grade->name ? 'selected' : "" }}>{{ $grade->name }}</option>                                            
                              @endforeach
               </select>
</div>


<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mt-2">
        @foreach($grade->subjects as $subject)
                 <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="{{$subject->slug}}" name="subjects[]" :value="selectedSubjects" /> 
                   <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{$subject->slug}}">{{$subject->name}}</label>
           @endforeach
  </div>
```

vue

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load',function(){
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data:{
                selectedSubjects: {!! $grade->subjects->pluck('name') !!},
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

THIS IS IMPOSSIBLE... I GIVE UP

Comment: can you show example of what is inside $grades that is sent to view from controller

Comment: inside the grades is a collection of subjects associated with that particular grade that is selected

Comment: though its a bit late, but then I thought better it be late than never

Comment: Man you are a genius!!…exactly what I wanted... Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per I have understood, you want to select grades from dropdown & show its corresponding checkbox as per subjects for the grades.

I would suggest to  create a vue component for that lets say `grades-component`,
in your blade you can add,

```
<form action="" class="form-control">
       @csrf
       <grade-component :grades='@json($grades)'></grade-component>
</form>
```

here in blade, $grades is the object(or array) you are passing via compact.  Basically it is to pass your data to the component, we will use that with help of props.

Now you can add your GradeComponent.vue in `resources->js->components->GradeComponent.vue`

**GradeComponent.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="container">

  <select v-model="selected_grade" @change="onChange($event)">
  <option v-for="grade in grading" :value="grade.slug">{{grade.name}}</option>
  </select>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mt-2" v-if="subjects !== null" v-for="subject in subjects">
          <input type="checkbox" :id="subject.slug" :value="subject.slug"/> 
          <label :for="subject.slug">{{subject.name}}</label>
        
    </div>
</div>

</template>
<script>

export default{
      props: ['grades'],
 data: function() {
    return {
      grading: this.grades,
      selected_grade: null,
      subjects : null
    }
  },
  methods: {
        onChange(event) {
          this.grading.forEach((obj, index) => {
            if (obj.slug === event.target.value){
                this.subjects = obj.subjects;
            }
          })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Now finally you can add it in app.js

```
Vue.component('grade-component', require('./components/GradeComponent.vue').default);
```

Then compile your vuejs code, I would use `npm run watch`

A similar one but with fake data, you can see https://jsfiddle.net/bhucho/2yu4nmws/3/,